# How to add time to Elasticsearch snapshot name?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want Elasticsearch snapshots named with date and **time** when they are created.

With the following template `snapshot-YYYY-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss`

Like this: `snapshot-2020-05-25_22-58-13`

How this can be done?

Elasticsearch documentation looks absolutely unclear about it, say no words and gives no example about time. I'm using v7.6 of Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some experiments I have found a solution. Here is the template that works:

```
<snapshot-{now{yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss|Europe/Oslo}}>
```

Note the time zone at the end. Without explicit time zone indication template generates time in UTC.

Comment: Docs for the date formatting are https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/api-conventions.html#api-date-math-index-names

Answer (score 0):

Docs from the previous version may shed some light on snapshot naming:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/modules-snapshots.html